# How to connect an ethernet printer to WiFi?

Tags: wireless-networking, printer, ethernet

I have a laser printer with an ethernet connection. (To be precise, it's a Brother DCP-L2550DN.) At our old apartment, we had ethernet cables in every room, so the printer connected to the network and we could print from every computer.

Now we've moved, and are using WLAN instead. So there is no ethernet connector in the room with the printer. Now I wonder: **How can I connect my ethernet printer to the existing WLAN?**

I believe I need an adapter that connects to the existing WLAN and offers an ethernet connector for the printer. But every device I found seems to do the opposite: They all connect to *an existing* network via ethernet, then provide *a new* WLAN.

I'm sure there must be an easy solution!

Comment: To add to the existing "ready-made" options shown below, you likely could run a small linux machine (which I guess from a security perspective may be easier to update, and likely could be made for about £17 with a raspberry pi 0 wireless and USB adapter!). Would require some knowledge on configuring linux though, and could run a print server via USB instead if needs be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### I need an adapter that connects to the existing WLAN and offers an Ethernet connector for the printer.

Use a Wireless bridge:

> A wireless bridge adapter, like the [Asus WL330GE](http://reviews.cnet.com/wireless-access-points/asus-wl-330ge-wireless/4505-3265_7-32744965.html), simply "catches" the Wi-Fi signal and converts it to Ethernet, letting connect those Ethernet-only devices without a long cable run.
>
> Just note that these products often involve some elaborate setup routines (such as installing software on a nearby PC, or accessing a setup screen through a web browser) that skew towards the skillset of an advanced user.

Source [How to get your Ethernet-only gadgets on your home network - CNET](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-get-your-ethernet-only-gadgets-on-your-home-network/)

That particular device is expensive at $189.95 and probably overkill for your needs but there are cheaper/simpler devices available:

> **Laptone N300 Wireless Mini Router**
>
> Laptone Wireless Mini Router is designed to conveniently extend the
> coverage and improve the signal strength of an existing wireless
> network. With 300Mbps wireless N speeds, Range Extender button,
> miniature size and wall-mounted design, extending a wireless network
> has never been easier.
>
> What's more, **its Ethernet port allows the device to act as a
> wireless adapter to turn a wired device into a wireless one.**

Typical price £14.99.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at Powerline communications. We use this setup at home to connect the Computer in the office, the wireless is flaky in that room.
It works by transmitting a signal through the existing power circuit in your home with, in its simplest form, 2 plug adaptors with Ethernet cables attached. It's a relatively cheap solution The TP-Link ones I use cost about £20 for the pair.